# What's the correct way to get rid of /public from a domain using node.js and nginx?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I've been structuring my website as follows:

- someSite

  - app.js
  - public

    - index.html
    - css
    - assets
    - Project1
    - Project2
    - ...

I'd like for the path to /public/Project1/index.html to be accessible by going to someSite.com/Project1, and similarly for subfolders. I've found this can be accomplished like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use('/public',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

app.get('/Project1', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/Project1/index.html');
});
```

But I don't know if this is standard, or inefficient. It's also breaking all of my relative calls, such as `<img src="../assets/someImage.svg">`, which no longer point to the correct place. It can be fixed by using absolute urls everywhere, but that feels wrong.

I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy server, which I think is the right place to make this change. My configuration is as follows:

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     someSite.com www.someSite.com;
        rewrite         ^(.*)   https://$host$1 permanent;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        root /var/www/someSite/public;

        server_name someSite.com;

        ssl_certificate /path/to/credentials.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/credentials.key;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

location / {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't figured out exactly what's wrong with my nginx configuration, but the hosting from node issue was just a matter of changing

```
app.use('/public',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

to

```
app.use('/',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

and removing subsequent `app.get` calls.